# What am I doing wrong with this session code?

Tags: php, mysql, permissions

I am trying to make the page inaccessible unless the user has a specific permissionlevel and is a user of the system.

I have provided my code below.

```
<?php
session_start();

        include 'login/config.php';

        if($_SESSION['username']=='user' && $_SESSION['permissionlevel']!='one');{
            echo "<script>you dont have permission to access this page</script>";
            header:("location:dashboard.php");
        }



?>
```

Where am I going wrong with the code?

EDIT:

Code modified with help of Neelesh, however it still isn't working.

Comment: Store permission level of a user in a session, check if permission level has acces to page, done!

Comment: I appreciate that, but I have asked HOW to do this, what code would I need to achieve this. I know what I have to do and have explaiend this I just don't know how to get there.

Comment: I'm not here to write code for you.. And I just told you HOW to do it.. Since you already know how to store something in a session and compare in an if, that's like all you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you search for an ACL implementation or how its work. The Zend Framework has a good implementation of this. Look here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html how its work.

regards

Comment: Thankyou, I will look at the ACL implementation and hopefully be able to create something from this that'll allow my users specific access rights. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

if suppose you have userroles like adminstrator and user

and permission levels one,two and three

based on this userrole and permission levels you can have check for that page if you are converting them into session while login

```
if($_SESSION['USERROLE']=='USER' && $_SESSION['PERMISSIONLEVEL']!='THREE')
{
echo "<script>you dont have permission to access this page</script>";
header:("location:index.php")
}
```

by this simple check you can give acces to a particular page if not redirect him to home page with an alert msg

Comment: I'll give that a try now, can I just ask if the ! is meant to be there on the second session string?

Comment: that's ur wish based on your requirement you can change it to == operator also...

Comment: ahhh I see, thankyou for the quick response I'll give it a go now!